# Searching for words in a line of a txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to process a txt file I created of songs and genres, but don't know how to tell python what to look for. The txt file is formatted like so:

> 1. 7/28/2012
>
> 1.1.  Lovin’ You Is Fun—Country
>
> [...]
>
> 1.100.    Call Me Maybe—Teen pop, dance-pop
>
> []2.  7/27/2013
>
> 2.1.  Crown—Hip hop

(brackets not in actual file)

I've tried writing code to find certain words in lines, but the code finds every line of the file as containing whatever string I pass it (even when that's obviously not the case). Here's the code:

```
try:
    infilehandle = open(afile, "r")
    alllines = infilehandle.read().splitlines(False)
    infilehandle.close()
except:
    alllines=None
    print "Unable to read file {0}".format(afile)
for aline in alllines:
    if aline.find("Country"):
        country_count += 1
    if aline=="1.   7/28/2012" or "2.   7/27/2013" or "3.   4/27/2013" or "3.   4/27/2013":
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

If the code worked the way I wanted it to, it would categorize each line by the first number on the line, then search for certain strings and add to a count for those strings. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
  if aline.find("Country") != -1:
```

or even better would be

```
  if "Country" in aline:
```

Also, your second if should read:

```
  if aline=="foo" or aline=="bar" or aline=="zom":
```

Answer (score 0):

Find doesn't return a boolean. It returns an int. In particular, it returns -1 if it doesn't find the string.

And as jonrsharpe mentions, you are using `or` incorrectly, also.

```
try:
    infilehandle = open(afile, "r")
    alllines = infilehandle.read().splitlines(False)
    infilehandle.close()
except:
    alllines=None
    print "Unable to read file {0}".format(afile)
    exit(1)
for aline in alllines:
    if aline.find("Country") != -1:
        country_count += 1
    if aline=="1.   7/28/2012" or
       aline=="2.   7/27/2013" or
       aline=="3.   4/27/2013" or
       aline=="3.   4/27/2013":
        pass  # I have no idea what you're trying to do here
```